# Common strings in swift project

Tags: swift4

I am creating a new project in Swift 4.x and I am looking for some best solution for my project. I wanted to know how we should manage common messages, JSON keys, network calls, common constants, etc... please see some of the examples below:

1. Common messages that I will use in the whole app:

   - OK
   - Done
   - Please enter the valid email
   - Please fill all the information
   - Are you sure you want to continue
   - etc...
2. I have JSON keys that are coming from the server:

   - name
   - token
   - email
   - age
   - app_identifier
   - date_of_joining
   - etc...
3. I have more than 200 server APIs:

   - getSomethingFromServer
   - deleteSometing
   - listSomething
   - clearAllCachedData
   - loginWithInformation
   - logout
   - etc...
4. I have few constants:

   - screen's full width
   - screen's full height
   - the interval for showing ads
   - the internal for the location fix
   - maximum retry for login
   - maximum supported video size
   - etc...

So my question where should I put all these things?

Should I create separate file and import wherever needed?

Should I use all these in the file itself where it is needed? But then the duplicate issue will arrive, for eg I need a URL or screens size in two different files.

Should I put all these in plist? But then I/O issue may come (not sure about it)?

Should I put all these in Application Delegate file?

Answer (score 6):

Create one constant class (Swift file in project):

```
public struct Constants {

    /************ SERVER URL *************/
    public static let CONFIGURE_URL : String = "YOUR BASE URL"
    public static let LOGIN_URL : String = "/login"

    /********** Login Preference ************/
    public static let USER_ID : String = "userId"
    public static let USER_TOKEN : String = "userToken"
    public static let USER_NAME : String = "userFname"

    /********    No Internet Connection     **********/
    public static let MESSAGE : String = "Please check your internet connection"
}
```

You can just call variable name like `Constants.MESSAGE` it will give `"Please check your internet connection"`

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea how to extend MESSAGEs with localization? Suppose I want to add support for 3 languages like English, Spanish and Chinese. For login keys and server URLs it is fine but for messages, I need localization support.

Comment: Then you need to add localize file and you can directly access those string yourLabel.text = "yourlabelInLocalize".localized()

Comment: ok, one more question, I have around 250+ URLs, 400+ common messages, 200+ keys, and 25+ constants, so putting all together in a single file (swift construct as you mentioned) is a good approach. What I mean, importing this big file in various other files via import is a good approach? Or should we breakdown something?

Comment: 250+ URLs , 200+ keys, 25+ constants declare in constant file and 400+ common messages declare these in localize file

Comment: Okay I'll do that